# Null result from left join

Tags: mysql

I have a strange result coming from a mysql query:

If I use

```
SELECT cbe.id, cbe.user_id, cbe_profile_gender ,bud.status,cbe.avatar
FROM findme as cbe 
LEFT JOIN findme_buddylist as bud ON cbe.user_id = bud.userid 
WHERE cbe.user_id<>2122 
AND cbe.avatar != "" 
AND bud.status != "2"
```

I get no result because the table ade39_findme_buddylist is empty

but if I remove the line :

```
AND bud.status != "2"
```

I get results showing that bud.status = NULL

What is wrong?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Normal comparison operators like `!=` and `=` don't work with `NULL`. Use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to check if a column is null.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions on the *second* table in a `LEFT JOIN` should be in the `in` clause:

```
SELECT cbe.id, cbe.user_id, cbe_profile_gender ,bud.status,cbe.avatar
FROM ade39_findme cbe LEFT JOIN
     ade39_findme_buddylist bud
     ON cbe.user_id = bud.userid and bud.status <> 2
WHERE cbe.user_id <> 2122 AND cbe.avatar <> '';
```